# Django standalone database script - Too Many Connections Error

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I don't know the conventions to saving or querying django objects in a standalone script so there may be some blatant errors in my code below.

Pretty much, the script is a standalone .py file which saves some models into the MySQL database.

Prior to this script I called export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = App.settings if that changes anything.

Here is the script:

```
    from Model.models import Model

    for a in stuff:
        Model(a.property, a.property, a.property).save()
```

Maybe some related hints, i've used the format of

```
for model in models:
    model.save()
```

many times prior before. They worked. However, non of them were standalone scripts, they were all in views.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try write a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) to avoid this. It could happen when ORM hasn't been  properly set up and every save() causes a new database connection.